# Nullability warnings in macOS headers after updating to Xcode 8.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

After updating to Xcode 8.3, I'm getting many new nullability warnings in macOS SDK headers. For example

`CoreText.framework/Headers/CTRubyAnnotation.h:175:5: warning: inferring '_Nonnull' for pointer type within array is deprecated [-Wnullability-inferred-on-nested-type]
    CFStringRef text[kCTRubyPositionCount] ) CT_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);`

`CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGColorSpace.h:175:13: warning: array parameter is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness-on-arrays]`

I could suppress the warnings, but I noticed they don't occur in a newly created project.

Here are the -W arguments from the command to compile the file which generate the warnings:

```
-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module
-Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module
-Wno-trigraphs
-Wno-missing-field-initializers
-Wno-missing-prototypes
-Wunreachable-code
-Wno-implicit-atomic-properties
-Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak
-Wnon-virtual-dtor
-Wno-overloaded-virtual
-Wno-exit-time-destructors
-Wduplicate-method-match
-Wno-missing-braces
-Wparentheses
-Wswitch
-Wunused-function
-Wno-unused-label
-Wno-unused-parameter
-Wunused-variable
-Wunused-value
-Wempty-body
-Wuninitialized
-Wno-unknown-pragmas
-Wno-shadow
-Wno-four-char-constants
-Wno-conversion
-Wconstant-conversion
-Wint-conversion
-Wbool-conversion
-Wenum-conversion
-Wshorten-64-to-32
-Wno-newline-eof
-Wno-selector
-Wno-strict-selector-match
-Wundeclared-selector
-Wno-deprecated-implementations
-Wno-c++11-extensions
-Wprotocol
-Wdeprecated-declarations
-Winvalid-offsetof
-Wno-sign-conversion
-Winfinite-recursion
-Wmove
-Wreorder
```

Here's a diff between the warnings in my project (left) and the warnings and the newly created project (right):

[image: Warnings diff]

Also, the Base SDK is set to Latest macOS (macOS 10.12) in both projects.

Comment: File a bug report with Apple, I'd say. Meanwhile, an easy workaround: make a new project and drag all your code and other resources into it.

Comment: I'm afraid my project file is far too complicated for that to be an easy work-around (multiple targets, etc.).

Comment: Aside from those warnings, does your project compile? I've noticed that I get a lot of false warnings if my project doesn't compile for some other reason. When I fix the issue, the warnings go away too.

Comment: Do you have `-Weverything` enabled?

Comment: @Wevah Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppress the warnings for your framework imports by bracing your prefix header like so:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnullability-completeness"

@import CoreGraphics; // Or some other module that imports CoreGraphics
// ...

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

If you aren't using prefix headers, well, they're useful in too many ways to count. Use them.

Answer (score -2):

It's not unusual for Apple to add more nullability annotations that were missing to the system headers as code is reviewed for nullability behaviour.

It is also not unusual that the default project templates would have some useful warnings not turned on.

I would recommend you compare the warning settings in a new project to those in yours. The SDK setting will also have an effect on which APIs are annotated.

Chances are, you'd get the same warnings in a new project and they're just not turned on by default.

Comment: But Uli, he specifically said "they don't occur in a newly created project".

Comment: But @matt, I specifically said that a newly created project may have warnings activated/deactivated in its build settings that are different from what his project has. Similarly, it may have a different SDK set. Do read the whole answer and don't downvote after the first sentence.

Comment: Then I think the onus is upon you to say what the build setting in question would be. Otherwise you're just guessing and this is really just a comment. I agree completely that comparing the build settings in a new project with the OP's own project is a great idea, but advising that (already implicit, indeed, in my own comment) is not an answer. I am sitting here looking right at the build settings and I can't see any likely candidate. Can you?